# WordPress automatically translate auto posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a WordPress blog and I am using the Automatic Youtube Video Posts plugin.
However, my site is in Danish and I would like for my posts to be in Danish.

Is there a way or a plugin that automatically translates the actual content of wordpress posts when they're posted?

Not just by using a real-time-translate-button, but actually changes the post data to the new language (So that it is read as Danish by google)

Answer (score 0):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/speaklike-worldwide-lexicon-translator/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/bens-translator/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/global-translator/

Those three examples are "automatic" translators, and work on posts . they also have a caching system for google.

However, since you "auto-post" - you might need to hook to them somehow. I never really used any, but I think that at least two of those are fully automatic and create the chosen translation on publish-time of post (and not real-time).

That being said - relaying solely on google translate service (or any other automatic service)  for translation will likely to produce unwanted results.